AvalonDock Dirkster: Set Position of a floating LayoutDocument to mouse cursor in ILayoutUpdateStrategy
In my LayoutUpdateStrategy i set some LayoutDocuments as FloatingWindow. This works by using Float(). The Position of this Window is then The Primary Screen with a minimum size. With IsMaximized i can maximize.
What i want is that the floating window appears at the cursors position with a specific size.
I thought
int floatingWindowWidth = 500;
int floatingWindowHeight = 300;

var cursorPosition = Cursor.Position;  
             
layoutDocument.FloatingWidth = floatingWindowWidth;
layoutDocument.FloatingHeight = floatingWindowHeight;
layoutDocument.FloatingLeft = cursorPosition.X - floatingWindowWidth / 2
layoutDocument.FloatingTop = cursorPosition.Y - floatingWindowHeight / 2

should work.
This works not so well. It seems that FloatingLeft and FloatingTop are using absolute monitor pixel (my screens have 1980x1080, 1980x1200, 1980x1200) values but Windows and the Cursor calculates and uses a virtual size which has a width of 2400 and a height of 1500 for every screen.
This results in a slidely moved position of the FloatingWindow.
Next idea was to get the the LayoutFloatingWindowControl and set the position but i have no idea how to get the object.
Any ideas on that?

At this time i have some how a workaround:
It seems like the virtual screen size depends on the scale factor of the primary screen (1.25). This is accurate for the height but not for the with.
There for i use this factor, which i get from the screen object to calculate the physical pixel position and then set it to FloatingTop and FloatingLeft:
.
.
.
int floatingWindowWidth = 500;
int floatingWindowHeight = 300;

GetUnScaledCursorPosition(out int physicalX, out int physicalY);

layoutDocument.FloatingWidth = floatingWindowWidth;
layoutDocument.FloatingHeight = floatingWindowHeight;
layoutDocument.FloatingLeft = physicalX - floatingWindowWidth / 2
layoutDocument.FloatingTop = physicalY - floatingWindowHeight / 2
.
.
.
public void GetUnScaledCursorPosition(out int physicalX, out int physicalY)
{
    // Get current cursor position (logical pixels)
    var cursorPosition = Cursor.Position;

    // Get the screen that contains the cursor
    var currentScreen = Screen.FromPoint(cursorPosition);

    // Get DPI scaling factor for the current screen
    float dpiScaleFactor = DpiHelper.GetDpiScaleFactor(currentScreen);

    // Convert logical pixels to physical pixels
    physicalX = (int)(cursorPosition.X / dpiScaleFactor);
    physicalY = (int)(cursorPosition.Y / dpiScaleFactor);
}

